# How can I cancel a job using if statement on slurm?

Tags: bash, slurm

My bash script will compare and read two values from different two files. If they aren't equal, the script should cancel the job on slurm. I think I should get the job-ID. But I dont know how to get the job ID and cancel it in bash script. How can I do this?

```
#!/bin/bash

#read the the first line (lets suppose a) from file1.txt
#read the the third line (lets suppose b) from file2.txt      
if  (a != b); then  
  # get the job-ID
  # cancel the job
 fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This possibly depends on the local environment settings. In my case when I submit a job to the scheduler the following string is output to stdout

```
Submitted batch job 1413273
```

You can capture this string and extract the id number, which you can then use to cancel the job in question

```
id=$(sbatch run.qscript | awk '{print $4}')
if [ $a -ne $b ]; then
    scancel $id
fi
```

Note that the comparison notation here, assumes that `a` and `b` are integers. If they are strings you should use

```
if [ "$a" != "$b" ]; then
```

Answer (score 0):

The slurm job id can be retrieved in the submission script from the `SLURM_JOB_ID` environment variable. So you need to write:

```
scancel $SLURM_JOB_ID
```